# erro no relatório - propriedade desconhecida na classe

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou usando jaspersoft para criar um relatório e recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

Unknown property 'RelPadraoAcesso' on class 'class sda.perfilacesso.model.report.RelPadraoAcesso'

Error retrieving field value from bean: RelPadraoAcesso.

A minha classe RelPadraoAcesso contém os campos que retornam da busca, que está funcionando.

```
public class RelPadraoAcesso implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -692759282661829181L;

private Integer uorg;
private String nomeSetor;
private Integer numero;;
private String nomeFunc;
private String siglaPadrao;
private String descPadrao;
private String Editavel;
private String silgaSistema;
private String siglaProjeto;
private String situacao;

public RelPadraoAcesso() {
    super();
}

public Integer getUorg() {
    return uorg;
}

public void setUorg(Integer uorg) {
    this.uorg = uorg;
}

public String getNomeSetor() {
    return nomeSetor;
}

public void setNomeSetor(String nomeSetor) {
    this.nomeSetor = nomeSetor;
}

public Integer getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getNomeFunc() {
    return nomeFunc;
}

public void setNomeFunc(String nomeFunc) {
    this.nomeFunc = nomeFunc;
}

public String getSiglaPadrao() {
    return siglaPadrao;
}

public void setSiglaPadrao(String siglaPadrao) {
    this.siglaPadrao = siglaPadrao;
}

public String getDescPadrao() {
    return descPadrao;
}

public void setDescPadrao(String descPadrao) {
    this.descPadrao = descPadrao;
}

public String getEditavel() {
    return Editavel;
}

public void setEditavel(String editavel) {
    Editavel = editavel;
}

public String getSilgaSistema() {
    return silgaSistema;
}

public void setSilgaSistema(String silgaSistema) {
    this.silgaSistema = silgaSistema;
}

public String getSiglaProjeto() {
    return siglaProjeto;
}

public void setSiglaProjeto(String siglaProjeto) {
    this.siglaProjeto = siglaProjeto;
}

public String getSituacao() {
    return situacao;
}

public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
    this.situacao = situacao;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException do Ireport
```

Há uma propriedade em JRBeanCollectionDataSource que mostra a opção booleana para que espaços vazios nos JRXML sejam lidos, e é ai o segredo basta colocar um false para que não leia os espaços em branco então ficaria deste jeito:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrbcds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados, false);
```

Fonte:http://miguellimapj.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/javalangnosuchmethodexception-do-ireport.html

Comment: que espaços em branco são estes . eu poderia retirá-los e resolver o problema?